# Saving regex results to variable

Tags: regex, applescript

I am using regex in applescript with Satimage osax. It is working fine, but I want to be able to save the returned matches to a variable to use

This is what I see in the Replies section of the applescript editor:

```
find text "(?i)(nhl|nfl|ncaa)" in "NFL games.pdf" with regexp
    --> {matchPos:0, matchLen:3, matchResult:"NFL"}
```

I was able to use a dialog box to display the result but I can't get it to save to a variable, no matter what I try.

Works:

```
display dialog matchResult of (find text "(?i)(nhl|nfl|ncaa)" in theName with 
regexp)
```

Doesn't Work:

```
set matchResult of (find text "(?i)(nhl|nfl|ncaa)" in theName with regexp) to 
keywordResult
set (matchResult of (find text "(?i)(nhl|nfl|ncaa)" in theName with regexp)) to 
keywordResult
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set keywordResult to matchResult of (find text "(?i)(nhl|nfl|ncaa)" in theName with regexp)
```

or

```
copy matchResult of (find text "(?i)(nhl|nfl|ncaa)" in theName with regexp) to keywordResult
```

You could also:

```
set keywordResult to (find text "(?i)(nhl|nfl|ncaa)" in "NFL games.pdf" with regexp)
matchResult of keywordResult --> "NFL"
matchLen of keywordResult --> 3
matchPos of keywordResult --> 0
```

Comment: That bottom example is exactly what I was looking for. I must have been staring at that one line too long. Thanks for the help.